# How do you show that the temporal part of an object's 4-velocity is decreasing as that object approaches the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, vectors, velocity, time-dilation

As a moving object approaches the speed of light then the temporal component of its 4-velocity should be decreasing. How do you derive and show that this is what is occurring?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: ...decreasing ???

Comment: @WillO I'm looking for a derivation of some kind which indicates that as an object approaches the speed of light - the time component of the 4-velocity reduces to zero.

Comment: And when you attempt that derivation, where do you get stuck?

Comment: @WillO, it's not the derivation I'm having a conceptual issue with. It's that a stationary object is thought to be traveling at the speed of light through time and then if an object is moving towards the speed of light through space. Then that speed of light velocity in the time direction should be lessening - not increasing. Thus shouldn't $u^{0}=\gamma c=\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\vec{v}^2}{c^2}}}$ be decreasing? Shouldn't the term be $c\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$ ?

Comment: If you increase $v$, you decrease the denominator of $u_0$, so you increase $u_0$.

Comment: @WillO, yes, I'm well aware of that and when you do that the c term increases without bound and thus that means there is something in the universe (in spacetime) that is moving faster than the speed of light. Which is impossible in Special Relativity.

Comment: The $c$ term is a constant.  You can set it to $1$.

Comment: @WillO, that's just a mathematical convenance to simplify equations. Relativity doesn't say that objects are moving through spacetime at the speed of 1. You even suggesting that proves you're not qualified to be debating this. Take care.

Answer (score 4):

In special relativity, with the most negative convention and $u^{\rho}$ the four velocity, we have:

$$u^{0}=\gamma c=\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\vec{v}^2}{c^2}}}$$

From here we see that if $\vec{v}^2$ increases we have that $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\vec{v}^2}{c^2}}}$, and so $u^{0}$, also increases.

Another way of seeing this is that: $u^{\rho}u_{\rho}=(u^{0})^2-(\vec{u})^2=c^2$

And since $\vec{u}$ is directly proportional to $\vec{v}$ we have that for $(u^{0})^2-(\vec{u})^2$ to be constant and equal to $c$ so if $\vec{v}$ increases means that also $(u^{0})^2$ must increase.

Comment: If a stationary object is thought to be traveling at the speed of light through time and then if an object is moving towards the speed of light through space. Then that speed of light velocity in the time direction should be lessening - not increasing. Thus shouldn't $u^{0}=\gamma c=\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\vec{v}^2}{c^2}}}$ be decreasing? Shouldn't the term be $c\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$ ?

Comment: @AnthonySmith the confusion here rests on which coordinates one is using. Specifically with the time component one could write either $\partial_{\tau}t$ or $\partial_{t}\tau$  clearly one is the OPs rekoning while the other is answers coordinates. Generally Anthony four velocity is defined w.r.t.  proper time, but yeah you can view it any way. That's relativity

Comment: @R.Rankin, sorry but no that cannot be correct and there is no confusion here except yours. The speed of light in spacetime must be the same for all observers in all reference frames.

Comment: @AnthonySmith  uhhhh.. Duh..

Comment: @AnthonySmith  Take a look here for what I was talking about. Sometimes you have to mix it up.  https://www.euclideanrelativity.com/

Comment: @R.Rankin, thanks but within that link (unless I missed it) there is no reference about 4 velocity.

Comment: @R.Rankin, then DUH!! this $u^{0}=\gamma c=\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\vec{v}^2}{c^2}}}$ says the speed of light is greater in some reference frames. That is unless of course you really don't understand what the equation is saying.

Comment: @AnthonySmith How it says that the speed of light is greater in some reference frame? It just says that the temporal part of the 4 velocity is always equal or greater than c.

Comment: @AndreaDiPinto, correct - it says that the 4 velocity is always equal to or greater then $c$. That's my issue. The maximum speed in spacetime is the speed of light so how can the 4 velocity be greater than $c$?

Comment: @AnthonySmith, you are confusing things. 1) The four velocity in spacetime is, no matter what the spatial velocity is, always equal to c since $u^{\mu}u_{\mu}=c^{2}$, 2) What it can't be grater than c is the (module of  the) spatial component $v$.

Comment: @AnthonySmith :  You appear to believe that if the temporal component of the 4-velocity is greater than $c$, then the speed is greater than $c$.  If you carefully write down your argument for this, you will discover your error.

Comment: @AndreaDiPinto, then what does this conceptually signify? - $u^{0}=\gamma c=\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\vec{v}^2}{c^2}}}$, or do you not know?

Comment: @WillO, then what does this conceptually signify? - $u^{0}=\gamma c=\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\vec{v}^2}{c^2}}}$, or do you not know?

Comment: @AnthonySmith, as said, it means that the temporal component increase when the velocity increases… For sure it doesn’t mean that a particle is going faster than $c$.

Comment: @AnthonySmith:  In standard notation, your expression represents the temporal component of the 4-velocity of a particle moving with velocity $v$.  But you've said in other comments that you don't mean $c$ to be a constant, in which case you have invented your own non-standard notation, in which case nobody can know what your notation means unless you choose to tell us.

Comment: And once again---if you are unsure of what your expressions signify,  the best way to clear your mind is to carefully write out each step of your derivation.  I can pretty much promise that if you do this, you will figure out what's confusing you.  Asking other people to do your work for you is not usually a fruitful way to understand things.

Comment: I was able to the figure it out. The 4-velocity is treating $c$ as a length, when you look at it that way it all fits and works out. Thank you for the thought-provoking conversations - all of you. It really helped.

Answer (score 0):

To help you answer your question...

Draw a spacetime diagram and the "future unit circle" (a hyperbola with asymptotes along the light cone), which marks 1 tick of proper-time along inertial worldlines
that met at a common event O. Those ticks mark the tips of the 4-velocities of astronauts met at event-O, traveling with different spatial velocities.

What do the temporal components of these 4-velocities look like
as the spatial velocities increase (that is, as these 4-velocities asymptotically tend toward the light cone?